# Query on Simple Vitali Lemma

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Wheedon's Analysis book has this lemma called "Simple Vitali Lemma":

Let $E$ be a subset of
$\mathbb{R}^n$ with
$|E|_e<\infty$, and let $K$ be a collection of cubes $Q$ covering $E$. Then there exist a positive constant $\beta$ (depending only on $n$), and a finite number of disjoint cubes $Q_1,\dots,Q_N$
in $K$ such that $\sum_{j=1}^{N}|Q_j|\geq\beta|E|_e$, where $\beta=5^{-n}$.

This would imply  $\sum_{j=1}^{N}|5Q_j|\geq|E|_e$.

My question is that, does this imply that $\bigcup_{j=1}^{N}5Q_j$ covers $E$?

The picture in Wikipedia seems to suggest so: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_covering_lemma

However I am not able to prove it rigorously. Just because it has greater measure than $E$ doesn't seem to directly imply it is a cover.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'm not sure what the notation $|\cdot|_e$ means, but I am pretty sure that no matter what it is, these counterexample should work, possibly with a small tweak.)

This can fail in a very stupid way; let $E=(-1,1)\cup\{400\}$ and $K$ contain only the cubes $[-1,1]$ and $[400,401]$. You can then take $Q_1=[-1,1]$ to satisfy the lemma but fail to get the awkward point.

Such an example could be made less silly by replacing $\{400\}$ with a set of very small measure, say $(400,400.00001)$, and we could then imagine this being a "subscenario" of a more "realistic" situation as well.

Comment: Good point. I wonder if a larger constant than 5 will make it a cover though (it certainly does in this case but I am not sure for all cases).

Comment: That notation means outer measure

Comment: I think the set $E=\bigcup_{n\geq0} [n,n+10^{-n}]$ can provide a counterexample for any constant you care to choose, since a finite collection of cubes could exclude most of the tail.